# Time-series classification using convolutional neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am working with time-series data. How can we use convolutional neural networks (CNN) for time-series classificaiton?

Answer (score 2):

For instance, using 1-D convolutions:
https://blog.goodaudience.com/introduction-to-1d-convolutional-neural-networks-in-keras-for-time-sequences-3a7ff801a2cf

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can try out 1-D convolutional neural networks, you can check this [code](https://github.com/hfawaz/dl-4-tsc/) on GitHub.